# Dynamically allocating memory and i CANNOT use calloc or realloc

Tags: c

Im still new to C so bare with me. I need to create a function called ResizeAlloc.c that returns type pointer to void and has three paramaeters. The first is named `pOld` and is of type pointer to `void`, while the second and third are type `size_t` named `newSize`, and `oldSize`.

ResizeAlloc either dynamically allocates an entirely new block of memory containing `newSize` bytes or, in effect, resizes an existing block in `pOld` containing `oldSize` bytes to contain `newSize` bytes. When resizing occurs all existing data that will fit into `newSize` bytes will be preserved. ResizeAlloc **may not** call `calloc` or `realloc` or any function or macro that you know does call them.

The following recommended implementation was also given:

```
if newSize is zero
  return a null pointer.
Else
  Dynamically allocate a new block containing newSize UNINITIALIZED bytes.
  If the allocation fails
     Return a null pointer.
  Else If pOld is a null pointer 
     Return a pointer to the new block.
  Else
     If newSize is greater than oldSize
        Copy oldSize bytes from pOld to the new block.
     Else
        Copy newSize bytes from pOld to the new block.
     Free pOld
     Return a pointer to the new block.
```

So using the implementation above, how would i create code that is similar to `realloc`, or `malloc`, without actually using them? Below is the supplied code that calls the `ResizeAlloc` function im supposed to create.

Im lost on how we dynamically allocate a new block containing `newSize` uninitialized bytes as the implementation above shows to get me started.

**Supplied Code:**

```
#define INSTRUCTOR_FILE    // DO NOT DEFINE THIS MACRO IN ANY FILES YOU CREATE

/***  YOU DO NOT NEED TO UNDERSTAND THE CODE IN THIS FILE TO WRITE YOURS  ***/

/******************** DO NOT MODIFY THIS FILE IN ANY WAY ********************/
/******************** DO NOT MODIFY THIS FILE IN ANY WAY ********************/
/******************** DO NOT MODIFY THIS FILE IN ANY WAY ********************/

//****************************************************************************
// Everything in this file was written to help test/verify your code and must
// not be altered in any way.  Do not rename this file or copy anything from
// it into your file(s).  This file does not necessarily represent good coding
// technique, proper formatting/style, or meet the requirements your code must
// meet.  You do not need to understand the code in this file to write yours.
//****************************************************************************
#ifdef INSTRUCTOR_FILE

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>

#define INIT_ARRAY_COUNT 128

void *ResizeAlloc(void *pOld, size_t newSize, size_t oldSize);

//
// Test: ResizeAlloc
//
int main(void)
{
   int tests = 0, errors = 0;

   signed char *initArray, *initArray1;
   signed char *cp;
   signed char value;
   int ix;

++tests;
#if 0
#define INIT_ARRAY_COUNT_FAIL UINT_MAX
   // Check for intentional allocation failure.
   initArray = ResizeAlloc(NULL, INIT_ARRAY_COUNT_FAIL, 0);
   if (initArray)
   {
      fprintf(stderr, "***ERROR*** ResizeAlloc: Array allocation "
         "failure not detected when size was too large.\n\n");
      free(initArray);
      ++errors;
   }
#endif

   // Check for intentional allocation rejection.
   ++tests;
   initArray = ResizeAlloc(NULL, 0, 0);
   if (initArray)
   {
      fprintf(stderr, "***ERROR*** ResizeAlloc: Array allocation "
         "rejection not detected when 2nd argument was 0.\n\n");
      free(initArray);
      ++errors;
   }

   // Check for successful allocation.
   ++tests;
   initArray = ResizeAlloc(NULL, INIT_ARRAY_COUNT, 0);
   if (!initArray)
   {
      fprintf(stderr, "***ERROR*** ResizeAlloc: Array allocation "
         "failed.\n\n");
      ++errors;
   }

   // Check for correct write/read.
   ++tests;
   value = SCHAR_MIN;
   // Initialize all elements.
   for (cp = initArray; cp < initArray + INIT_ARRAY_COUNT; ++cp)
      *cp = value++;
   value = SCHAR_MIN;
   ix = 0;
   // Test all elements.
   for (cp = initArray; cp < initArray + INIT_ARRAY_COUNT; ++cp)
   {
      if (*cp != value++)
      {
         fprintf(stderr, "***ERROR*** ResizeAlloc: Incorrect value at "
            "element %d.\n\n", ix);
         ++errors;
      }
      ++ix;
   }

   // Check for correct size increase.
   ++tests;
   initArray1 =
      ResizeAlloc(initArray, INIT_ARRAY_COUNT * 2, INIT_ARRAY_COUNT);
   // Initialize upper elements.
   value = SCHAR_MAX;
   ++tests;
   for (cp = initArray1 + INIT_ARRAY_COUNT;
      cp < initArray1 + INIT_ARRAY_COUNT * 2;
      ++cp)
   {
      *cp = value--;
   }

   value = SCHAR_MIN;
   // Test lower elements.
   ix = 0;
   for (cp = initArray1; cp < initArray1 + INIT_ARRAY_COUNT; ++cp)
   {
      if (*cp != value++)
      {
         fprintf(stderr, "***ERROR*** ResizeAlloc: Incorrect value at "
            "element %d.\n\n", ix);
         ++errors;
      }
      ++ix;
   }

   value = SCHAR_MAX;
   // Test upper elements.
   ix = INIT_ARRAY_COUNT / 2;
   for (cp = initArray1 + INIT_ARRAY_COUNT;
      cp < initArray1 + INIT_ARRAY_COUNT * 2;
      ++cp)
   {
      if (*cp != value--)
      {
         fprintf(stderr, "***ERROR*** ResizeAlloc: Incorrect value at "
            "element %d.\n\n", ix);
         ++errors;
      }
      ++ix;
   }

   // Check for correct size reduction.
   ++tests;
   initArray =
      ResizeAlloc(initArray1, INIT_ARRAY_COUNT / 2, INIT_ARRAY_COUNT * 2);

   value = SCHAR_MIN;
   // Test 1/2 of lower elements.
   ix = 0;
   for (cp = initArray; cp < initArray + INIT_ARRAY_COUNT / 2; ++cp)
   {
      if (*cp != value++)
      {
         fprintf(stderr, "***ERROR*** ResizeAlloc: Incorrect value at "
            "element %d.\n\n", ix);
         ++errors;
      }
      ++ix;
   }

   free(initArray);

   const char *plural = errors != 1 ? "s" : "";
   if (errors)
      fputc('\n', stderr);
   fprintf(stderr, "C2A1E5: %d tests %d error%s.\n",
      tests, errors, plural);

   return 0;
}
#endif
```

Comment: Are you looking to write your own allocator? I'm not entirely clear on this from the question.

Comment: Please clarify whether you can use `malloc()`, I thought it is forbidden implicitly, but in the answer somebody (@BillLynch) understood obviously differently and I cannot plame them, because the description does not actually forbid it. Using malloc just seems too easy for this....

Comment: From the pseudo code, it looks like the idea is to implement `realloc()`

Comment: @Hasturkun yes, i need to create my own allocator.

Comment: @ Yunnosch i can not use malloc or realloc for this

Comment: Wait, are you saying you can't use `malloc()`, `calloc()`, or `realloc()` ??

Comment: @MarkBenningfield yes that is correct.

Comment: Good luck with that

Comment: ResizeAlloc either dynamically allocates an entirely new block of memory containing newSize bytes or, in effect, resizes an existing block in pOld containing oldSize bytes to contain newSize bytes. And it is recommended that i use the implementation described above in the original question. Without using malloc(), realloc(), or calloc().

Comment: Do you have a heap to grab memory from? There's got to be more to this question.

Comment: @yhyrcanus the instructor supplied a seperate function that calls this function. Are assignment was to create our own allocator without the use of built in tools such as malloc, realloc, etc. using the implementation listed above. I am finding nothing online in terms of help with creating a functions with the same functionality as something like realloc.

Comment: You should probably verify that this is the intention, given that your provided code calls `free()`, which would probably be fatal if called on memory that wasn't allocated by `malloc()`. I'd guess the intent was that you only use `malloc()` and `free()`.

Answer (score 3):

> I am having trouble just starting and dynamically allocating a new block containing newSize of uninitialized bytes.

You can use the [`malloc()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/malloc) function to allocate uninitialized memory.

Comment: i can not use malloc, or realloc, i need to create my own allocator from what i can tell is very simular to realloc

Comment: I suspect you are misunderstanding your instructor, and you should reach out to them.